# Symfony error: The class xxx was not found in the chain configured namespaces App\Entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I created a new symfony project with an entity `Company` and a contoller `CompanyController`. I want to get the results from a database but I keep getting this error: `The class 'App\Repository\CompanyRepository' was not found in the chain configured namespaces App\Entity` and I don't know why.

I searched the internet but I read only answers that are solving errors when the namespace is not App\Entity. Please help me.

The files are all stored in the src folder as it is when creating a new symfony project. I didn't change any configuration files so every configuration is on default.

Here is my entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\CompanyRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=CompanyRepository::class)
 */
class Company
```

After that there are just getter and setter.

Here is my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Repository\CompanyRepository;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

#[Route('/api/company', name: 'company')]
class CompanyController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route(name: 'company.get', methods: ["GET"])]
    public function getCompanies(): Response
    {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $repository = $entityManager->getRepository(CompanyRepository::class);

        $companies = $repository->findAll();
        $data = [];

        foreach ($companies as $company) {
            $data[] = $company->toArray();
        }

        return $this->json([
            'data' => $data
        ]);
    }
}
```

Here is my Company Repository:

```
<?php

namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\Company;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;

/**
 * @method Company|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method Company|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method Company[]    findAll()
 * @method Company[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 */
class CompanyRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Company::class);
    }

    // /**
    //  * @return Company[] Returns an array of Company objects
    //  */
    /*
    public function findByExampleField($value)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->andWhere('c.exampleField = :val')
            ->setParameter('val', $value)
            ->orderBy('c.id', 'ASC')
            ->setMaxResults(10)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
        ;
    }
    */

    /*
    public function findOneBySomeField($value): ?Company
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->andWhere('c.exampleField = :val')
            ->setParameter('val', $value)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult()
        ;
    }
    */
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your entity ? you may have an error with your repository configuration

Comment: try this  in your company Entity class 
@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CompanyRepository")

Comment: @OussMaL'aireBien Unfortunately, this isn't working as well. Same error again.

Comment: can you show us your CompanyRepository file pls?

Comment: Please share more details. Where are these files stored? How did you configure the entity mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the controller, replace `$repository = $entityManager->getRepository(CompanyRepository::class);` with
`$repository = $entityManager->getRepository(Company::class);`

And replace `use App\Repository\CompanyRepository;` with `use App\Entity\Company;`

Because `getRepository()` expects the Entity class, instead of the Repository class.

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Company;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

#[Route('/api/company', name: 'company')]
class CompanyController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route(name: 'company.get', methods: ["GET"])]
    public function getCompanies(): Response
    {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $repository = $entityManager->getRepository(Company::class);

        $companies = $repository->findAll();
        $data = [];

        foreach ($companies as $company) {
            $data[] = $company->toArray();
        }

        return $this->json([
            'data' => $data
        ]);
    }
 }
```

Comment: This is throwing `Class 'App\Controller\Company' does not exist` error.

Comment: add this "use App\Entity\Company;"